# Why shouldn't gui threads live in multithreaded apartments?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, com

The COINIT - an enumeration used to specify whether a windows thread is in a single or multithreaded apartment - documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms678505(v=vs.85).aspx) states that:

> The multi-threaded apartment is intended for use by non-GUI threads. Threads in multi-threaded apartments should not perform UI actions. This is because UI threads require a message pump, and COM does not pump messages for threads in a multi-threaded apartment.

Why shouldn't threads in multi threaded apartments perform UI actions? What is wrong with having a message loop in a thread in a multi threaded apartment? Does COM somehow provide an automatic message loop for a thread in a single threaded apartment?

Comment: You can create a thread, have it join MTA, then run a message pump on it; nothing stops you. However, it is generally pointless. If you are doing this in a COM server, and a client calls a method on your COM object, this call will execute on a *different* MTA thread (one from a COM runtime-managed pool). Also, if you make an out-of-apartment COM call on this thread, the call will block and your UI will appear hung (whereas an out-of-apartment COM call from an STA thread spins a modal message pump while waiting for the call to return).

Comment: And yes - when COM creates an STA thread on your behalf, this thread runs a message pump. This happens when an MTA thread creates an in-process STA COM object.

Comment: "What is wrong with having a message loop in a thread in a multi threaded apartment?" That's not the problem. The problem is that (as it says in the documentation you quoted) "COM does not pump messages for threads in a multi-threaded apartment". This means that if COM needs to wait, it will wait without pumping messages, which hangs your UI. COM does pump messages while waiting in single-threaded apartments.

Comment: So @IgorTandetnik when you make a call to an out of apartment COM object from a STA thread, your normal message loop (or some other message loop) runs while waiting? If the latter, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: See [INFO: Descriptions and Workings of OLE Threading Models](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150777): "The client's thread enters a COM provided message loop when it makes an outgoing call." See also [`CoRegisterMessageFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693324.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a bit backwards, a UI thread primarily requires a message loop so that it can receive notifications from Windows and other processes.  A message loop is the universal solution to the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  With the operating system and other processes producing, the UI thread consuming.

A UI thread uses lots and lots of code that is not thread-safe.  This includes major features implemented in COM, like drag+drop, the clipboard, the shell dialogs, ActiveX controls like a browser.  And a raft of code that was never made thread-safe because the programmer didn't have to make it so, much easier to write.  Those features require an STA thread, in other words a thread that initializes COM by passing COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED to CoInitializeEx().

That is a *promise* to COM that the thread will be a good citizen, it is not allowed to make blocking calls and must pump a message loop.  It is the message loop that COM uses to marshal a call from a worker thread to the STA thread in order to keep a COM object thread-safe.  When all the calls are made from the same thread then there's never a safety issue.  The underlying call is SendMessage(), with a ton of plumbing to copy the function arguments from one stack to another.  CoInitializeEx() creates a hidden message window owned by the STA thread that processes the message and actually makes the call.  Safely.